# Protractor configuration - is there a way to seperate some of the spec files from running asycnronously?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have some protractor tests for my angular web application (conf.js file at bottom of this post).

There are several tests stored in different .js files and then loaded in.

In addition to the tests, I am using multiple capabilities so that it can test my web site at various resolutions, firing up 5 browsers at once.  This works fine.

One of my test suites however, needs not to run at the same time as all of the other capabilities, this is because I have to require the server to change some settings for the tests I am performing to work.  I am not able to 'mock' these server calls, as the response from the server is crucial to the test I am running, and I need to see that I called and recieved the expected response from the actual server rather than a mocked up object.

Because of this, if any of the other tests from one of the other capabilities are running at the same time they get the wrong information back from the server.

As a work around I set ***maxSessions: 1*** in my conf file, which stops the above problem, but means my tests take about forever to run!

Is there a way to give the spec declaration two arrays, so it knows to run a certain bunch of tests only when nothing else is running? ( i invented the seperateSpecs property to illustrate what i'm getting at)

For example :
**specs: [testCanRunInTandom1.js, testCanRunInTandom2.js, testCanRunInTandom3.js],**

**seperateSpecs: [MustRunAloneWithoutOtherCapabilities.js, MustRunAloneWithoutOtherCapabilities2.js]**

I've had a look about, but can't find anything.  An answer of 'no you really cant do that' would be acceptable, but i'm hoping someone knows some secret command you can give to protractor!

Here is my current conf.js file for reference :

```
 var specFiles = ['NavigationTests.js', 'HeaderTests.js', 'TableTypeTests.js', 'DepositTests.js','loginTests.js','userPrefsTests.js', 'progressBarTests.js', 'aboutPageTests.js'];


// multiCapabilities stuff set now near bottom of file to make it easier to add/change/remove capabilities

var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-html-screenshot-reporter');
var request = require('request');

var desktopSpec=  
{
    // Desktop
   'browserName': 'chrome',
   'chromeOptions' : 
   {
       args: ['--lang=en', '--window-size=1690,800']
   },
   specs: specFiles,

};

var iPhone3gSpec=
{
  //iphone 3G portrait
 'browserName': 'chrome',
 'chromeOptions' : 
 {
  args: ['--lang=en',
         '--window-size=320,480']
 },
 specs: specFiles
};

var iPhone3gLandscapeSpec=
{
  //iphone 3G landscape
 'browserName': 'chrome',
 'chromeOptions' : 
 {
  args: ['--lang=en',
         '--window-size=480,320']
 },
 specs: specFiles
};

var iPadSpec=
  {
    //ipad portrait
   'browserName': 'chrome',
   'chromeOptions' : 
   {
    args: ['--lang=en',
           '--window-size=1024,768']
   },
   specs: specFiles
  };

var iPadLandscapeSpec=
{
  //ipad landscape
 'browserName': 'chrome',
 'chromeOptions' : 
 {
  args: ['--lang=en',
         '--window-size=768,1024']
 },
 specs: specFiles
};

var multiCapabilities=[];
multiCapabilities.push(desktopSpec);
multiCapabilities.push(iPhone3gSpec);
multiCapabilities.push(iPhone3gLandscapeSpec);
multiCapabilities.push(iPadSpec);
multiCapabilities.push(iPadLandscapeSpec);


// Configuration file
exports.config = {
  directConnect: true,

  // Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    includeStackTrace: false,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  },

  // Run the tests in the different windows sizes
  multiCapabilities: multiCapabilities,

   onPrepare: function() {
      // Add a screenshot reporter and store screenshots to `/tmp/testresults/screnshots`: 
      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
         baseDirectory: 'tmp/testresults/screenshots'
      }));
   },

   maxSessions: 1
   };
```

Comment: Yes it is possible but you will need to use the gulp build tool with run-sequence (https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence) or spend a lot of time coding your own solution.